# Appending <li> value to <ul> in jquery dialog box is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery dialog box in which a textbox, button and list has been added. I am trying to append the inputted value of textbox into list on the same dialogbox without loading the page.

```
<a href="#"  class="view" >View</a>
<div id="dialogBox" title="details" style="display: none;">
    <div id="list" class="ui-popup">
        <label for="name">Add name</label><br/>
        <input style="width: 50%;" type='text' id="name" value="" >
        <input type="submit" class="save" id="save" value="SAVE"/>

        <ul id="namelist">
            <li>Reena</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var view = function(eventData) {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog({resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:950,
        modal: true
    }).css("maxHeight", window.innerHeight - 200);
};

$('.view').click(view);

var update = function(e) {
    var name = $("#name").val(); 

    $.ajax({
        url : "someApi.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : "function=updatenames&name="+name,
        success: function() {
            $("#namelist").append('<li>'+name+'</li>');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert( "Could not Update" );
            return false;
        }
    });
};

$('.save').click(update);
```

I have tried like above, ajax function and all working correctly,but in success function appending list to ul is not working

Please share your suggestion.

Comment: Try this $('.save').click(function(){update();});

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: Are you using angular js because `{{name}}` ?

Comment: No,that is twig..I will edit to simple text

Comment: Created fiddle..Please refer here https://jsfiddle.net/k28LzeLv/1/

Comment: You need to include `jquery` in your fiddle.

Comment: Have you checked the console to confirm that you have not appended empty `<li></li>`?.  Make sure `name` is defined inside the success callback.

Comment: I have included jquery but it is not working :-(

Comment: You have a case issue with your `dialogBox` selector it needs to be in camel case like  `$("#dialogBox").dialog({resizable: false,...` where as you have it in small case

Comment: Thats my bad..it is a typo here

Comment: Is it working after you correct that typo?

Comment: Unfortuantely, your fiddle is not running. It is hard to debug the issue :(

Comment: ya,Im trying to solve it.If you can,please

Comment: fiddle wont work as you using external php file... change this line code... `$("#namelist").append("<li>' + name + '</li>");`

Comment: Created new one without any external file still not working..https://jsfiddle.net/m91qkxpd/

Comment: Have you included jQueryUI?  If you replace `dialog` with `show`, it works.

Comment: Ya I have included this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: `#name` is in a modal window - to get its value you need to add the modal window name before the input id - try this: `var name = $('#dialogBox #name').val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#name` is in a modal window - to get its value you need to add the modal window name before the input id - try this: `var name = $('#dialogBox #name').val()`:

```js
var view = function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog({resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:950,
        modal: true
    });
};

$('.view').click(view);

var update = function(e) {
    var name = $('#dialogBox #name').val(); 

     $("#dialogBox #namelist").append('<li>'+name+'</li>');
      
};

$('.save').click(update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"   integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="#"  class="view" >View</a>
<div id="dialogBox" title="details" style="display: none;">
    <div id="list" class="ui-popup">
        <label for="name">Add name</label><br/>
        <input style="width: 50%;" type='text' id="name" value="" >
        <input type="submit" class="save" id="save" value="SAVE"/>

        <ul id="namelist">
            <li>reena</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi siderxylon..I am getting the name value properly..Thats not a problem..Appending that value is not working for me.But your case it is working.

Comment: How to add that value in the 1st line of ul

Comment: Above 'reena'?  Just `prepend()` instead of `append()`.

Comment: After adding new value to existing ul..can we refresh the list ?

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet... its working. let me know

```js
var view = function() {
    $("#dialogBox").dialog({resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:950,
        modal: true
    });
};

$('.view').click(view);

var update = function(e) {
    var name ='Nithya'; 

     $("#namelist").append('<li>'+name+'</li>');
      
};

$('.save').click(update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"   integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<a href="#"  class="view" >View</a>
<div id="dialogBox" title="details" style="display: none;">
    <div id="list" class="ui-popup">
        <label for="name">Add name</label><br/>
        <input style="width: 50%;" type='text' id="name" value="" >
        <input type="submit" class="save" id="save" value="SAVE"/>

        <ul id="namelist">
            <li>reena</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$("#namelist").append("<li>' + name + '</li>");`  Change single quote to double quote.. This will work.. let me know

Comment: Hi scene..it is working here..but what thing I have missed..The same code only I have followed.

Comment: This works because it doesn't try to get a value from an element in a modal window.

Comment: Thanks for your help scena